# Which free dashboards are also MQTT brokers?

Tags: mqtt

I'm trying to find a dashboard which:

- Has pretty widgets for data display
- Can subscribe to, and display MQTT data that I publish
- Can publish commands to subscribers (eg: "Driveway light switch: turn on")
- Is free for home / hobby usage

Surprisingly, it's quite hard (for me anyway) to Google for something which fits the bill.

My specific use case: I'm a maker who is trying to remotely measure temperature and control a room's air conditioning system.

Comment: This question sounds like it would be better suited to our [software recommendarions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Comment: http://thingspeak.com/
https://ch.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/mqtt-api.html

Comment: Did you checked the comprehensive [list of MQTT dashboards](https://github.com/hobbyquaker/awesome-mqtt#visualization-dashboards) for various platforms?

Answer (score 7):

A self hosted instance of [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/) with the Node-RED [Dashboard UI](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-dashboard) nodes installed, with an instance of mosquitto running to supply the MQTT broker.

The whole thing will run happily on a Raspberry Pi (in fact Node-RED comes pre-installed on the raspbian image), or you could throw up a minimal lightsail (or equivalent) instance to host it in the cloud.

Just make sure you [secure](https://nodered.org/docs/security) the Node-RED editor if you intend to expose this to the internet.

Answer (score 4):

[uBeac](https://www.ubeac.io/?utm_source=iot.stackexchange.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3930) is a new freeware visualization tools which we have developed and it is Beta version. It is not opensource, but fully free to use.

You can define a gateway and you will get a unique URI. You can set the URI in you gateway or device to send HTTP/MQTT data to.

These are some of its features:

- Team, building, floor plan definition
- Real-time data visualization
- Custom dashboard design using different widgets
- Define sensor types,
  units, and prefixes Map visualization
- ...

It supports generic Json data format and different predefined gateway as well. If you don't want to use predefined payload formats, they are open to develop your custom payload processing.

Comment: I found this incredibly difficult to use, with very limited (and often outdated) documentation and bizarre abstractions. I'd give this one a skip.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Thingsboard](https://thingsboard.io/): **Device management, data collection, processing and visualization for your IoT solution**.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [MQTT Tiles](https://flespi.com/tools/mqtt-tiles) dashboard that accompanies the [flespi MQTT broker](https://flespi.com/mqtt-broker) (with MQTT 5.0 support)

Answer (score 0):

Chk  [MqttDesk](https://ioctrl.com/) MQTT Client .
Create unlimited Dashboards with 27 nos. Of different widgets.
Developed specifically for Makers, developers.

Comment: Please edit the question to declare any affiliation you have with the service you mentioned in the answer.